# ActivityIndicator is throwing type error undefined is not an object

Tags: react-native

I am working on react native project. What I want to do is rendering Spinner(ActivityIndicator) in my screen while data is fetching. When in this form it is working.

```
state = {
    audios: '',
    isLoading: true
}


render() {

    if (this.state.isLoading) {
        return <ActivityIndicator
            style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: 'white' }}
            animating={true}
            color='#1b92e7'
            size='large'
        />;
    }
```

but ActivityIndicator wraps my TopBar component. I want to use it under TopBar. When I try to render this it's throwing me Type Error undefined is not an object.

```
state = {
    audios: '',
    isLoading: true
}

componentDidMount() {
    xmls = 'my envelope';
    Axios.post('url to get data', xmls, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'key',
            'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
        }
    }).then(response => {
        this.setState({ audios: response.data, isLoading: false });
    }).catch(err => {
        console.warn("Error", err);
    });
}

removeJsonTextAttribute = (value, parentElement) => {
    try {
        var keyNo = Object.keys(parentElement._parent).length;
        var keyName = Object.keys(parentElement._parent)[keyNo - 1];
        parentElement._parent[keyName] = value;
    }
    catch (e) { }
}

indicator = () => {
    return <ActivityIndicator
        style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}
        animating={true}
        color='#0da24d'
        size='large'
    />
}

render() {

    let isLoading = this.state.isLoading;

    let convert = require('xml-js');

    const options = {
        compact: true,
        ignoreDeclaration: true,
        spaces: 4,
        ignoreAttributes: true,
        textFn: this.removeJsonTextAttribute,
        elementNameFn: function (val) { return val.replace('SOAP-ENV:', '').replace('ns:', ''); }
    }

    let audio = convert.xml2json(this.state.audios, options);
    let audio_obj = JSON.parse(audio); // it throws error in here.
    let url= audio_obj.Envelope.Body.url;

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <TopBar name={"Name"}  />
            <Spinner loading = {isLoading}>
            <WebView
                startInLoadingState={true}
                renderLoading={this.indicator}
                allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
                source={{ uri: url}}
                onError={() => {
                    ToastAndroid.showWithGravity(
                        'Error while getting url.',
                        ToastAndroid.LONG,
                        ToastAndroid.CENTER,
                    );
                }}
            />
            </Spinner>

        </View >
    );
}
```

Here is my Spinner Component;

```
const withSpinner = Component => ({loading, children, ...props}) => {
    if (loading) {
        return <ActivityIndicator 
            style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: 'white'}}
            animating={true}
            color= 'red'
            size='large'
        />;
    } else {
        return (
           <Component {...props}>
               {children}
           </Component>
        )
      }
    };
```

Here is a article [Higher Order Component Spinner](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2017/11/15/higher-order-component-for-rendering-spinner-in-react-native-app.html)

What am I missing in here? I hope you guys can help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your Spinner should be

```
const Spinner = withSpinner(View);
```

instead of WebView

Comment: where is the actual error thrown? https://snack.expo.io/@arnaudmo/aW5zYW quick expo that shows a stripped down version working. btw it definitely should be `View` and not `WebView` as pointed out by Chirag, otherwise you would get a blank space as you are nesting 2 WebViews ?

Comment: It is throwing Type Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'audio_obj.Envelope.Body' but without using Spinner Component only ActivityIndicator is working but it is wrapping my TopBar. I want Activity Indicator under it.

Comment: I think you should try console logging your `audio_obj` and see what the contents are.

Comment: It is working correctly with View instead of WebView. There is a error with url object of mine. Can you explain why  I have to use View instead of WebView so I can mark it is as resolved. Thanks for contributions.

Comment: @tron: If you look at the `withSpinner` in the HOC, the component passed to it as argument is the parent component. 

Sorry if that was not clear in the blog. :) As the author of that blog, I should have been more clear in my explanation there.